# Check remote host domain name which does CURL post request?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have simple question.

Lets say php at example.com domain makes curl (POST) request to a domain example2.com. Is there a way to check weather POST request is done from domain example.com and not from other domains?

Comment: Could you explain a little further .. If you do curl request from one server how are you thinking it could possibly be done from another ? or is this the ONE server but you're hoping the request to be domain identified ?

Comment: Not really. You could require that a header is set with the sending domain, but it can be forged.

Comment: You can check HTTP header `Referer` but, as @Repox wrote, it can be easily forged

Comment: HTTP header Referer is empty when I do curl request. I check request variables and it seems that only remote ip address is valid info. Isn't there any way to know from which domain name that request comes..... ??